# Can we have a sticky "Add Answer" button on the iOS app?

Tags: feature-request, answers, ios-app

It often occurs that there are many answers on a single post and thus makes it time-consuming to scroll down and click "Add Answer" on the iOS app, a perfect example is the [PPCG Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/56456), with a whopping 1360 answers. Can we get a sticky "Add Answer" button so I don't have to scroll down?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is iOS app specific or it's on Android too. If anyone uses the Android app, may you comment if this is the same case on Android?

Comment: I'd like to use this opportunity to state that I noticed a lot of iOS and Android app feature requests, bugs, etc.  I hope there's someplace where the developers can get these questions.

Comment: @user6035379 The devs check meta, so reported bugs and feature requests get visibility.  The only problem is that there is no dedicated mobile team.  Search around for the various posts asking SE employees about the mobile apps, you'll find additional information.

Comment: Did you say there's no dedicated mobile team?

Comment: @user6035379 there is only one developer, who works for the iOS app. Android app got no developer working on it, so its bugs are not fixed and no new features are ever added. (for over a year, and SE are not planning to hire any new developer.)

Comment: @JAL iOP app does have a dedicated "team" of one developer (Brian). While not ideal, he's fixing most of the bugs and adding tons of new features.

Comment: Yes, I know Brian works on iOS.  I don't consider one person a team, but I can understand why you do.